# Change/insert characters in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been learning a lot of stuff as I go today, so hopefully, this question is clear. I have the below code which shows all posts written by the logged-in user as long as the post is a specific category. The part I'm trying to change is the URL. The goal is to click on the link, and it takes the user to the search page, using the post name as the search terms. So for example, if there post name is "iPhone X", the URL would take the user to the search page for "iPhone X" and show all results.

I'm close, but the problem is...as written, the URL that is generated is 
.../?s=iPhone-x (notice the hyphen)

Search results are written with a "+" for each space
.../?s=iPhone+X

Is there a way I can either restructure the URL in the code, or somehow tell the system to replace all "-" with "+" before generating the URL?

```
    function user_posts_exercise( ) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;
    $items='';   
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
        'status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'category_name'       => 'Exercise'
        );
    $jobs = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($jobs as $job){
      $link = '<a href="'.home_url('/?s='.$job->post_name).'">'.$job->post_title.'</a> 
    </BR>'; 
      $items = $items . $link;
      }
    return $items;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'exercise_user_posts', 'user_posts_exercise' );
```

Comment: The `$job->post_name` is actually the post "slug" and it's been formatted that way by wordpress internationally to create urls, why not search with the `$job->post_title`?

Comment: When you use '$job->post_title' the resulting URL has a space between the characters which in a URL, of course, doesn't work

Comment: The browser should deal with space without a problem, either way you can force it with `urlencode($job->post_title)` to convert space to + characters for the correct encoding or use the word press function `add_query_arg( 's', $job->post_title, home_url() )` and see what it gives you

Comment: The urlencode worked! Thank you so much

Comment: I'll reply as an answer so you can mark it as accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser should deal with space without a problem, however you can use urlencode to escape the characters.

```
urlencode( $job->post_title )
```

to convert space to + characters for the correct encoding or use the word press function

```
add_query_arg( 's', $job->post_title, home_url() )
```

and let it deal with the encoding